# How to hide refind's "Booting OS" splash screen?

Tags: refind

I just want a blank screen.

I tried these 3 configurations (changes to refind.conf) but it didn't work.

- not setting "use_graphics_for" (this is the default behavior)
- setting "user_graphics_for" (no OS supplied as parameter)
- setting "use_graphics_for windows"

Any ideas? Thank you.

PS. I'm booting into windows.

Comment: You could maybe try disabling textmode.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Arch and I had the same problem!

I had set:

```
use_graphics_for osx,linux,grub
```

And I would still see the blue Booting OS splash screen.
I fixed it by adding a manual entry for Arch:

```
menuentry "Arch Linux" {
     icon /EFI/refind/themes/glow/icons/os_arch.png
     loader /EFI/systemd/systemd-bootx64.efi
     ostype Linux
     graphics on
}
```

With the `graphics on` set, all I saw was a black screen then my bootup animation.

I asum you could do that same by adding one for windows like this:

```
menuentry "Windows" {
    icon /EFI/refind/icons/os_win.png
    loader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
    ostype Windows
    graphics on
}
```

Note: The above is an example that may not work for you please make sure that paths will work on your computer.